# is there any way to block the possibility to resize the text in a webpage using ctrl + scroller of the mouse

Tags: webbrowser-control, cross-browser, browser

i guess maybe using javascript im gonna do it.... but if anybody knows a better and faster way to do it .. easily im gonna appreciate any ideas...
thanks!...

this is to make impossible for a user to view badly the page increasing the text or doing something like a zoom in the browsers ...

ive got some QA engineers asking me that .....

thanks!

Comment: I think you're going to get a lot of "You shouldn't be trying to do that" answers because (unless you have some really odd, good reason you're not telling us...) you really shouldn't be trying to do that

Comment: I agree. Unless you can give a *very good* reason why you want to do this you will probably only get the (correct) answer: "Don't do it!"

Comment: I agree with the 'don't do it' guys, but I'm curious as to the intent of blocking your users' usage of your site. How would that come under the remit of 'QA' (assuming QA is quality-assurance)?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very bad idea from a usability/accessibility point of view. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you block that key combination, the user would still be able to increase the zoom level via the "View" menu.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a good reason, I doubt there is one, so I agree that you shouldn't do it.  It's a fun little challenge though, so I have a possible answer, though I don't really know if it would work.

First, have a `font-size: 70%` or whatever percent you want in an outermost containing element.

Then, create a dummy testing element with:

```
display:block;
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
font-size:1em;
font-family:Arial;
```

Find the actual height of the element (say, 25px) and then test it over and over again on a timer (window.setInterval()).  If it doesn't match, change the font-size percentage on the outer element until it does.

Comment: +1 for posting something that answers the question instead of something that rejects the question.